# Typescript Component getting `undefined`

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a problem with using this Component like a function where I am getting `undefined`. I have the import and NgModule in the index.ts. The SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent has the export class and

index.ts

```
import { SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent } from "../../Components/Review/SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent,
```

SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: ".select-internal-edit-reviewers",
    templateUrl: "/Views/Components/Review/SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent.html"
})
export class SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent extends SelectableGrid<PotentialMdReviewerDto, string> {
```

TemplatesUpdatePopupsComponent.ts

```
     export class TemplatesUpdatePopupsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
        
        @ViewChild(SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent) selectInternalEditReviewersComponent: SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent;

//Error undefined
this.selectInternalEditReviewersComponent.initPotentialReviewers(undefined, undefined, true);
```

Comment: a ViewChild it's only available: 1.-In (or after) ngAfterViewInit,2.- if you use "{static:true}", e.g. `@ViewChild(SelectInternalEditReviewersComponent,{static:true}) ...`. But you can use this **only** if the component is always visible -it is not under a *ngIf-

Comment: I guess I am not understanding I have it after AfterViewInit

Comment: where you write the `this.selectInternalEditReviewersComponent.initPotentialReviewers(...)`?

Comment: its after ngAfterViewInit down at the bottom. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h3nkeh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: can It be how I am compiling the typescript?